# getElementsByClassName is not working whereas ID is working. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using both **`getElementsByClassName`** and **`getElementById`**. The later one (ID) is working but Class is not working. I have multiple **`td`** so i want to use class instead of ID but it is not working. Where is the issue?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td><span style="vertical-align:middle;">Id is</span>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="#" title="Book ID" onmouseover="document.getElementById('viewa').src='images/edit.png';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('viewa').src='';"><img src="" id="viewa" align="right" width="15px" height="15px" /></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Book Name</td>
<td><span style="vertical-align:middle;">Name is </span>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="#" title="Book Name" onmouseover="document.getElementsByClassName('viewb').src='images/edit.png';" onmouseout="document.getElementsByClassName('viewb').src='';"><img src="" class="viewb" align="right" width="15px" height="15px" /></a></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is a `HTMLcollection` you can't just assign

Comment: Please make sure sure you understand the difference between jQuery and vanilla JavaScript. You are using the latter expecting it to behave as the former.

Answer (score 2):

If you are okay with using jquery, then you can check the answer below. But if you really want to use plain javascript, then you can try this code.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td><span style="vertical-align:middle;">Id is</span>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="#" title="Book ID" 
onmouseover="onmouseoverevent(this)" onmouseout="onmouseoutevent(this)"><img 
src="" id="viewa" align="right" width="15px" height="15px" /></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Book Name</td>
<td><span style="vertical-align:middle;">Name is </span>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="#" title="Book Name" 
onmouseover="onmouseoverevent(this)" onmouseout="onmouseoutevent(this)"><img 
src="" class="viewb" align="right" width="15px" height="15px" /></a></td>
</tr>

</table>

<script>

function onmouseoverevent(elem)
{
elem.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src='images/edit.png';
}

function onmouseoutevent(elem)
{
elem.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src='';
}
</script>
```

Comment: This won't work because the array index is at the wrong position : `getElementsByClassName[0]('viewb')` should instead be `getElementsByClassName('viewb')[0]`

Comment: Thanks @Henkan Working fine. But for every **td** I have to change [0] and replace it with the array number. Actually i want to show the image on hover for each td but css is not working. Is there any method by which i can apply same class on multiple so that same image can be shown on hover on each td ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @ManishMaharjan Working fine. But for every td I have to change [0] and replace it with the array number. Actually i want to show the image on hover for each td but css is not working. Is there any method by which i can apply same class on multiple so that same image can be shown on hover on each td ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`GetElementById` returns a single element, since ID is unique. But class isn't, so `GetElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements.

So you have to use `GetElementsByClassName("foo")[0]` for example, to get the first element with the class foo.

And if you want to execute it on all elements with the class, you'll have to do a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting inline vanilla JavaScript into HTML attributes kind of beats the purpose of using a library (which you aren't using anyway). The sensible jQuery idiom would be something like this:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $("table a")
    .on("mouseover", function(){
      $(this).find("img").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/15x15");
    }) 
    .on("mouseout", function(){
      $(this).find("img").attr("src", "");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>

<tr>
<td>ID</td>
<td><span style="vertical-align:middle;">Id is</span>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="#" title="Book ID"><img src="" id="viewa" align="right" width="15px" height="15px" /></a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Book Name</td>
<td><span style="vertical-align:middle;">Name is </span>
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="#" title="Book Name"><img src="" class="viewb" align="right" width="15px" height="15px" /></a></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

If you also get rid of inline CSS in favour of proper stylesheets code maintainability will certainly improve.